# How include a .a library in a c++ project

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I have to include a library with the extension .a in my project in C++. 
How can I link to the project in visual studio? And how can I include the library in the C++ code? The library is written in C, is it could be a problem?

Comment: It will be a problem.

Comment: Where did you get the `.a` file? Are you sure it's been compiled for Windows? Usually (statically linked) Windows libraries have `.lib` as their extension, not `.a`.

Comment: .a files are a Unix/Linux thing....

Comment: .a files are for *nix, you need a .lib file equivalent

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but if you are able to use cmake to configure your project instead of trying to do it from inside visual studio, it becomes significantly easier.

Comment: Is there a way to change in .lib extension?

Comment: If you were given a `.a` file to use in a windows project, someone messed up. You can't just change the extention, as a `.a` file is a statically linked binary compiled specifically for *nix. To make the library work you would need the `.lib` version of the library, which you would download separately, or compile from source.